# Unable to modify Chaincode in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I downloaded the fabric-sample example from the command in linux, 
given in the document "http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.0-beta/getting_started.html#install-prerequisites"

I followed the document to start the network, and script.sh 
is running successfully.

now when I am modifying the chain code from my local system at "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02"

chaincode modification is not reflecting in the output.

please suggest me, how to run my own chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is to run your own chaincode, the recommended way is to follow the [chaincode developers guide here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html). Normally, the chaincode is started and maintained by peer, but this chaincode dev mode allows user to start chaincode for easier testing and development. If you are starting by modifying existing chaincode, you may omit the code-building section and concentrate on the other steps (creating proper directories, building them etc)

Answer (score 0):

When you start your network, you get some Peers and an Orderer. In that step you copy the chaincode that it's in the predefined directory, i.e. a predefined chaincode is copied for you. You define that directory in the `docker-compose-cli.yaml` file, in the line `- ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode` So, if you want to change the chaincode that is copies to your Blockchain, you should change in that directory.

So, any change that you do in your local machine won't have any effect on the chaincode of the Peer. If you want to run your own chaincode, you have to define it previously, before starting up your network. Then, you will hava it in the corresponding docker container.

You can develope your own chaincode and pass it to the ***cli*** container by executing the following command:

`docker cp yourchaincode.go cli:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/mychaincode/yourchaincode.go`